# Is Offset Edge feature removed?

Tags: interface

I cannot find the offset edge feature anymore in Blender 3.6.1 LTS. The attached image is from the internet, representing an old version. Where can I locate this feature now?
[image]

.
EDIT: adding image as asked...
[image]

Comment: It's in the same place for me as in the image you posted. Blender 3.6.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: For me it is not there. Do we have to activate it somewhere? I don't remember.

Comment: nothing changed. it is still there in 3.6. what OS are you using? can you share a screenshot of how it looks on your pc

Comment: I edited my question to add the image. plz have a look

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to enable the addon called *Mesh: Edit Mesh Tools*.